# How can I put the contents of My Account > Order into a separate page, Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

How can I output the contents of my account > orders on a different page in php?

I managed to output the table when there are orders, but when there are no orders, it shows blank.

How can I show the orders content when blank in a different php page?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: This shows my full order table but not the empty message .                                 /* Show Orders inside My Account Page */
function shortcode_my_orders_two( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'order_count' => -1
    ), $atts ) );

    ob_start();
    wc_get_template( 'myaccount/orders.php', array(
        'current_user'  => get_user_by( 'id', get_current_user_id() ),
        'order_count'   => $order_count
    ) );
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('my_orders_two', 'shortcode_my_orders_two');

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the template file for orders it starts like this

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_account_orders', $has_orders ); ?>

<?php if ( $has_orders ) : ?>
```

If there are no orders it's never going to loop through that content, which is good because it would be broken if it did.  If you really need the orders table to show up even if it's empty then you'll want to recreate the table from the template file somewhere else and pull that in.  If you're including this template on your other page it shouldn't be showing up as blank with no orders though, there should be a no orders message.

Comment: but if you go to My Account and click on the tab "Orders" it does show a message that states that you do not have any orders yet and has a "Go To Shop" link. I want to pull that message too from the empty state.

Comment: I used this code                                                                                                   
function shortcode_my_orders_two( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'order_count' => -1
    ), $atts ) );

    ob_start();
    wc_get_template( 'myaccount/orders.php', array(
        'current_user'  => get_user_by( 'id', get_current_user_id() ),
        'order_count'   => $order_count
    ) );
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('my_orders_two', 'shortcode_my_orders_two');

Comment: Interesting, the only thing I can think of off the top of my head is that maybe some of the global variables WooCommerce relies on aren't defined when you're calling it.  Also  when you say it shows blank do you mean it just doesn't output anything or is your footer missing too, you might have a fatal PHP error killing your page silently.  Also, as a general rule, don't use `extract()`, it makes your code hard to read, especially when you're only pulling one or two variables out of `$atts`.